# Lock screen notification text

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am building and easy android app.
I am having trouble with notification. When the app receive the notification it shows it properly as heads up with all the picture and the text, while on the lock screen, if the phone is locked, does not show the text. To see the text I have to swipe the notification down.

This is the code:

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            bigText.bigText(body);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_luceterna_notifica_90)
                    .setContentTitle("Luceterna")
                    .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_lux)).getBitmap()))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

            mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
           .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Can please anyone help me? I cannot find any answer to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the last code line:                      mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since you asked this question, but I encountered same problem today, and found a sollution.

To solve this problem, you have to override *NotificationCompat* `setContentTitle` and
`setContentDescritption`

With *BigTextStyle* ones: `setBigContentTitle` and `bigText`
You have to use them both, with same texts inside. So, your code would look like:

```
String title = "Title";
String description = "Description";

NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
bigTextStyle.bigText(description);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(description)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(bigTextStyle);


NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle("Notification!") // title for notification
            .setContentText("Hello word") // message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

An example to help you